# Is there a way to scroll to bottom of div or container in React without scrolling the entire page to the bottom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, scrollview

I will keep it simple, I have an App component that has three child components such as component A at the top, B in the middle, and C in the bottom. Component A has a scrollable feature via

`overflowY: 'scroll'`

I want the contents in component A to scroll to the bottom. Is there a way to do this with React Hooks? So far everything I have seen here uses the old class form that I cannot make work with hooks or uses code that pushes the entire window down, which would be the whole App component in my case.

Comment: I don't see how anything would be much different from class components to function components. What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Can you provide more context what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with the npm package

`react-scroll-to-bottom`

Adding it here in case others have the same issue and did not know about the package.